# R: Reduce size of rpart object

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to aggregate in a list multiple CART models built with `rpart::rpart` .

I just realised that each model stores quite a lot of (meta?)data in `$terms` and `$where` (over 10MB of data per model in my case) which makes my final list un-manageable.

It seems to me that the summary given by `print(my_rpart_object)` should be sufficient to describe the object and run predictions, so I wonder if there is a way to trim / compress rpart trees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it: each `rpart` object was carrying an environment with it. To remove it :

```
rpart_model <- rpart(...)
environment(rpart_model$terms) <- NULL
```

List of 21 part objects went from 1.2GB to 8MB.

Comment: Small question: How did you go about trouble shooting this ? That is, how did you identify the different object in the environment and further identified that terms was the object taking a large chunk of memory ?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this as well. I found setting the "where" element of the rpart tree to NULL significantly reduced the tree's memory footprint:

```
rpart_model <- rpart(...)
rpart_model$where <- NULL
```